# How can I solve the infinitely recursion run problem?

Tags: c, recursion, graph

The question is about to ask the get degree of connection between two users(each user has a friend list). Instructions and examples are given in the pictures. Below is my code, this code work with degree of 2 or less but with bigger or no connection it runs infinitely. I was wondering what was the error here.
'''

```
int get_degrees_of_connection(User *a, User *b)
{
  if(strcmp(a->name,b->name)==0){
    return 0;
  }
  if(in_friend_list(a->friends,b)){
    return 1;
  }
  FriendNode *temp = NULL;
  temp = a->friends;
  User *current = NULL;
  a->visited = true;
  while(temp!=NULL){
    current = temp->user;
    if(current->visited == true){
      continue;
    }
    int val = get_degrees_of_connection(current,b);
    if(val!=-1){
      return 1+val;
    }
    temp = temp->next;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKSRo.png)

Comment: It would be helpful if you added a tag for the language you're using here. C?

Comment: How many degrees of friends do you consider a connection?  If you don't care about when there are more than 6 degrees for example then keep a counter for how far you have recursed.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
  while(temp!=NULL){
    current = temp->user;
    if(current->visited == true){
      continue;
    }
```

Will run forever when `current->visited == true`. There's nothing that updates `temp` before the continue statement.  That's why it will run forever.

If I had to guess, you probably want to invoke `break` not `continue` when you hit a cycle in the graph traversal.